# Width of ScrollViewer inside StackPanel automatically change with it's Content's width

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer

The `Width` of a `ScrollViewer` remains "normal" if it is used like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Rectangle Width="2500"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Saying "Normal" I've meant that the `ScrollViewer`'s `Width` is going to be the same as the `Grid` (1500 in my case) as I didn't mention their `Width` myself. At least that's what i know.

But, if the above portion is taken inside a StackPanel like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Rectangle Width="2500"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

then the `ScrollViewer`'s `Width` become 2500 as it's Content's `Width`.

What's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout procedure in XAML has two phases **Measure** and **Arrange**.

During the **Measure** phase, *usually*, most panels will ask their children "What size do you want to be?" (this will effectively walk down the tree).  And the parent of the children can decide what size it wants to be based on it's children.  It returns this `Size` in its `MeasureOverride` method.

Once everything has been measured, it's time to actually **Arrange** and layout things on the screen.  This is when the *actual* size of elements is determined.  The system starts by telling each element "This is how much space you have."  Each panel then, starting at the top, can then tell it's child where to be within its space and how much space it actually has to take up (done by calling `Arrange` on each child in the `ArrangeOverride` method of a parent custom panel).

You can see the full documentation for this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview).

So in your two examples the outcome is different because of how Grids and StackPanels behave:

1. With the Grid as a root, in your top example, it takes up the available space and tells its children they *have to* fit inside it.  So the ScrollViewer says it wants to be larger because of it's child rectangle, but in the end the Grid says you only have 1500 units of space because that's all it was given.  So the ScrollViewer will show a scrollbar if you turn on `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to let you pan to see the whole rectangle.
2. With the StackPanel as a root, it will *expand itself* to accommodate the size of its children.  Therefore, when the ScrollViewer tells the Grid it wants to be this size for its contents, that gets passed up through the Grid to the StackPanel.  When it comes time to Arrange, the StackPanel tells the Grid that it has all the space it requested, which is the extra space the Rectangle wanted.  This extra space just gets clipped by the page/window in the end when its displayed.

This is why there's so many different layout panels available as they all behave differently during these two steps to arrange one or more content items for a desired effect.  It's also why using StackPanels everywhere can be tricky as they're always greedy compared to other panels which will behave more 'predictably'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. :)